# Mongo aggregate - Split interval value into months affected

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a tricky aggregation of data in mongo and I have no idea how to achieve it directly in mongo without no later data processing.

**Here is an simplified example of documents in my collection**

```
[
    {
        "from" : ISODate("2017-01-15T00:00:00.000Z"),
        "to" : ISODate("2017-02-15T00:00:00.000Z"),
        "value" : 1000
    },
    {
        "from" : ISODate("2017-02-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
        "to" : ISODate("2017-02-28T00:00:00.000Z"),
        "value" : 2000
    },
    {
        "from" : ISODate("2017-02-20T00:00:00.000Z"),
        "to" : ISODate("2017-03-14T00:00:00.000Z"),
        "value" : 1000
    }
]
```

No I would like to get monthly sum of values belonging to a specific month.

```
[
{janurary: 500}, /* 1/2 of interval id 1 is January so take half the value */
{february: 2833}, /* 500 + 2000 + 333 */
{march: 666}, /* 2/3 of interval id 3 is March */
]
```

Calculation has to be precise so I can't simplify things by saying all months have exactly 30 days. But what I can do is provide this information from code for each month of the interval. So it should be possible to provide this query information `january2017 = 31 days, february2017 = 28 days, march2017 = 31 days`

I know I could do this in my node.js code but there might be A LOT of documents in that DB so I would rather not fetch all of these to server to perform the calculation.

Comment: Do your dates ever touch more than two subsequent months? Can both `from` and ´to´ be within the some month? Also, which MongoDB version are you using?

Comment: Right. So the second question, I guess, is already answered as part of your question since the second sample document has both `from` and `to` in February...

Comment: as for Q1 they can and also they can span across multiple months Q2 mongo 3.6

Answer (score 1):

Pah, I hope somebody else comes up with a nicer answer but here is one way of getting there:

```
db.collection.aggregate({
    $addFields: {
        dayFrom: { $dayOfMonth: "$from" },
        dayTo: { $dayOfMonth: "$to" },
        monthFrom: { $month: "$from" },
        monthTo: { $month: "$to" },
        numberOfDays: { $subtract: [ { $dayOfMonth: "$to" }, { $dayOfMonth: "$from" } ] },
        numberOfMonths: { $subtract: [ { $month: "$to" }, { $month: "$from" } ] },
    }
}, {
    $addFields: {
        numberOfDaysInFromMonth: { $dayOfMonth: { $subtract: [ { $dateFromParts : { year: { $year: "$from" }, month: { $add: [ "$monthFrom", 1 ] }, day: 1  } }, 1 ] } },
    }
}, {
    $addFields: {
        numberOfDaysAccountingForFromMonth: { $subtract: [ { $add: [ "$numberOfDaysInFromMonth", 1 ] }, "$dayFrom" ] },
        numberOfDaysAccountingForToMonth: { $subtract: [ "$dayTo", 1 ] }, // assuming the "to" day does not count anymore
    }
}, {
    $addFields: {
        totalNumberOfDays: { $add: [ "$numberOfDaysAccountingForFromMonth", "$numberOfDaysAccountingForToMonth" ] }
    }
}, {
    $addFields: {
        percentageAccountingForFromMonth: { $divide: [ "$numberOfDaysAccountingForFromMonth", "$totalNumberOfDays" ] },
        percentageAccountingForToMonth: { $divide: [ "$numberOfDaysAccountingForToMonth", "$totalNumberOfDays" ] },
    }
}, {
    $facet: {
        "from": [{
            $group: {
                _id: "$monthFrom",
                sum: { $sum: { $multiply: [ "$value", "$percentageAccountingForFromMonth" ] } }
            }
        }],
        "to": [{
            $group: {
                _id: "$monthTo",
                sum: { $sum: { $multiply: [ "$value", "$percentageAccountingForToMonth" ] } }
            }
        }]
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        total: { $concatArrays: [ "$from", "$to" ] }
    }
}, {
    $unwind: "$total"
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: "$total._id",
        sum: { $sum: "$total.sum" }
    }
})
```

Some remarks:

1. You will need to refine that to match your precise definition of
   what forms part of a date range and how to count the number of days
   ("is 2018-01-30 to 2018-01-31 **one** day or is it **two** days?").
2. You might be able to beautify that query using [$let](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/) and
   some nesting. I thought it would be easier to use subsequent `$addFields` stages to make the beast easier to follow through.
3. The code does not support `from` and `to` values that touch more than two months (e.g. 2018-01-01 to 2018-03-01).